# Print when Userform1 unloads via CommandButton1

Tags: excel, printing, vba

Userform1 ComandButton1 code is similar to this (contains more lines of CheckBox checks):

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set WB = ActiveWorkbook

If CheckBox25.Value = False Then
        WB.sheets("PQC 1025").Delete
    Else: CheckBox25.Value = True
    End If

Unload Me
End

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

The second macro will be a Format/Print macro:

```
Sub Format_Print()

Dim ws As Variant
For Each ws In Workbook

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftFooter = "" & Format(DateTime.Now(), "yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss")
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightFooter = "Page &P of &N"

Next

For Each ws In Workbook

ActiveSheet.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True

Next

End Sub
```

I honestly don't know where to start.  I'm not a strong coder and it took me a while to get as far as I did.

I would like this macro to automatically happen when Userform1 unloads after use of CommandButton1 (the Okay button).  I **do not** want this second macro to start automatically when CommandButton2 is used to unload Userform1 (the Cancel button).

Any input on how I might try this would be helpful.

Comment: Just before `Unload Me` in `CommandButton1`, type this `Format_Print`

Comment: I attempted this; debug error of Type mismatch with "Each ws In Workbook" in the Format_Print script. Corrected by listing as "Option explicit" atop the code and then am getting compile error Variable not defined on the line "Each ws in Workbook."  I changed Variant to WorkSheet to correct that line and the variable not defined is now the word Workbook in "For Each ws in Workbook."  I believe the UserForm may be independent of the Workbook?  Not sure if that's possible, but I can't figure out why a userform can't define a Workbook otherwise.

Comment: Edited code in Format_Print to list "Set wb = ActiveWorkbook," "Dim ws As Worksheet," "For Each ws In wb."  Getting object doesn't support this property or method error on the "For Each ws In wb".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a new button on the main form to format/print.  I fixed a few of the issues I was having with my initial format/print code, removed all of the dimension and setting and simply said "sheets.select" which was the simple fix to object errors.

I had no check that people selected the correct sheets, so I figured this was a safer approach.